# Getting specific fields' values of a text using awk, sed, and grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to get the values of the name fields of the following text, using `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or similar.

```
{
    "cast": [
        {
            "character": "",
            "credit_id": "52532e3119c29579400012b5",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 23629,
            "name": "Brian O'Halloran",
            "order": 0,
            "profile_path": "/eJsLxovTdcm6QK9PDB2pCe5FMqK.jpg"
        },
        {
            "character": "",
            "credit_id": "52532e3119c2957940001315",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 19302,
            "name": "Jason Mewes",
            "order": 1,
            "profile_path": "/so3nT2vgSCZMO2QXDVHF3ubxaFX.jpg"
        },
        {
            "character": "",
            "credit_id": "52532e3119c295794000133d",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 23630,
            "name": "Jeff Anderson",
            "order": 2,
            "profile_path": "/vjt5WhpJAx0jxvmiGc5PAOBzzb7.jpg"
        },
        {
            "character": "Silent Bob",
            "credit_id": "52532e3219c2957940001359",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 19303,
            "name": "Kevin Smith",
            "order": 4,
            "profile_path": "/3XXThSMqHQgQFjM4bMJ25U1EJTj.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "crew": [
        {
            "credit_id": "55425dbe9251410efa000094",
            "department": "Visual Effects",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 1419667,
            "job": "Animation Manager",
            "name": "Richard J. Gasparian",
            "profile_path": null
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "5544521dc3a3680ce60037e8",
            "department": "Art",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 1450356,
            "job": "Background Designer",
            "name": "Tristin Cole",
            "profile_path": null
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "554a142dc3a3683c84001851",
            "department": "Art",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 1447432,
            "job": "Background Designer",
            "name": "Nadia Vurbenova",
            "profile_path": null
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "554bcd2b9251414692002c9b",
            "department": "Production",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 1447493,
            "job": "Location Manager",
            "name": "Simon Rodgers",
            "profile_path": null
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "52532e3219c29579400013cd",
            "department": "Production",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 19303,
            "job": "Executive Producer",
            "name": "Kevin Smith",
            "profile_path": "/3XXThSMqHQgQFjM4bMJ25U1EJTj.jpg"
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "52532e3319c2957940001405",
            "department": "Production",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 59839,
            "job": "Producer",
            "name": "Harvey Weinstein",
            "profile_path": "/k4UCnh7n0r5CEjq30gAl6QCfF9g.jpg"
        },
        {
            "credit_id": "52532e3319c29579400014a7",
            "department": "Production",
            "gender": null,
            "id": 1307,
            "job": "Producer",
            "name": "Bob Weinstein",
            "profile_path": "/oe5Oxp034UOubnvZqqhurp6a1EP.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

Comment: That looks like JSON - use `jq`

Comment: Hope this is not a homework question!
try `grep -oE "name[^,]*," <inputfile> | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g' | awk -F: '{print $2}'`

Comment: If you are okay with using python. `cat x.json | python -c import sys, json; d = json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print(d["cast"][1]["id"]; )`

Answer (score 4):

[***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is the right tool for processing JSON data:

getting all `name` key values:

```
jq '[.cast[], .crew[] | .name]' file
```

The output:

```
[
  "Brian O'Halloran",
  "Jason Mewes",
  "Jeff Anderson",
  "Kevin Smith",
  "Richard J. Gasparian",
  "Tristin Cole",
  "Nadia Vurbenova",
  "Simon Rodgers",
  "Kevin Smith",
  "Harvey Weinstein",
  "Bob Weinstein"
]
```

---

To get just a list of strings, use the following:

```
jq '.cast[], .crew[] | .name' file
```

The output:

```
"Brian O'Halloran"
"Jason Mewes"
"Jeff Anderson"
"Kevin Smith"
"Richard J. Gasparian"
"Tristin Cole"
"Nadia Vurbenova"
"Simon Rodgers"
"Kevin Smith"
"Harvey Weinstein"
"Bob Weinstein"
```

---

To get just a list of unquoted `"` strings, add the `-r` (`--raw-output`) option:

```
jq -r '.cast[], .crew[] | .name' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `jq` approach :

```
jq '.[]?|.[]?|.name' file
"Brian O'Halloran"
"Jason Mewes"
"Jeff Anderson"
"Kevin Smith"
"Richard J. Gasparian"
"Tristin Cole"
"Nadia Vurbenova"
"Simon Rodgers"
"Kevin Smith"
"Harvey Weinstein"
"Bob Weinstein"
```

---

**Note:** The `.foo?` usage <sup>[[ see manpage ]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?)</sup> does not output even an error when `.` is not an array or an object.

Answer (score 0):

Helo buddy, with awk just do it:

```
awk '/name/{gsub("[\",]*", "");print $2}' yourFile.txt
```

Best regards!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try with another following awk solutions too here.

**1st approach:** IN case you need to have double course around the and name values.

```
awk -F'[:,]' '/name/{sub(/^ +/,"",$2);print $2}'   Input_file
```

**2nd approach:** In case if you need only the name's values then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F'[":,]' '/name/{print $5}'   Input_file
```

**Explanation of 1st approach:** Simply making (:  and ,) as field separators and then looking for string name in a line if it contains then substituting the initial space of 2nd field with NULL and then printing the 2nd field's value.

**Explanation of 2nd approach:** Making (" : and ,) as field separators. Then searching for string name in a line, if it has it then printing the 5th field of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the JSON file rather than use a regex.

You can use Ruby to do:

```
$ ruby -0777 -r json -lane '
                   d=JSON.parse($_)
                  (d["cast"]+d["crew"]).each { |x| p x["name"] }' json
"Brian O'Halloran"
"Jason Mewes"
"Jeff Anderson"
"Kevin Smith"
"Richard J. Gasparian"
"Tristin Cole"
"Nadia Vurbenova"
"Simon Rodgers"
"Kevin Smith"
"Harvey Weinstein"
"Bob Weinstein"
```

Or if you want to separate cast from crew:

```
$ ruby -0777 -r json -lane '
                   d=JSON.parse($_)
                   %w(cast crew).each {|w|
                   puts "#{w.capitalize}:"
                  (d[w]).each { |x| puts "\t#{x["name"]}" }}' json
Cast:
    Brian O'Halloran
    Jason Mewes
    Jeff Anderson
    Kevin Smith
Crew:
    Richard J. Gasparian
    Tristin Cole
    Nadia Vurbenova
    Simon Rodgers
    Kevin Smith
    Harvey Weinstein
    Bob Weinstein
```